# Strange behavour of bytecode generated for Scala code

Tags: scala, interface, abstract-class, traits, bytecode

I am playing with Scala traits.

```
trait Animal{
  def speak = println("speaking..")
  def comeToMaster: Unit
}

class Cat extends Animal{
   override def speak: Unit = println("meow....")
   def comeToMaster = println("catch me if you can..")
}

object Sample extends App{
 val kity = new Cat
  kity.speak
  kity.comeToMaster
}
```

But when i see the bytecode generated by Scala compiler,

```
javap -c Animal.class 
Compiled from "Sample.scala"
public abstract class Animal$class {
  public static void speak(Animal);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #13                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #15                 // String speaking..
       5: invokevirtual #19                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public static void $init$(Animal);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Notice there is only speak method in bytecode. Where is comeToMaster method? I tried again after deleting all class files. Still, it gives me the same result. So, I am not getting this strange behaviour of Java bytecode generated by Scala compiler.

But when i see the bytecode of Cat class, there are both methods.

```
javap -c Cat.class 
Compiled from "Sample.scala"
public class Cat implements Animal {
  public void speak();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #18                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #20                 // String meow....
       5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public void comeToMaster();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #18                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #29                 // String catch me if you can..
       5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public Cat();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #32                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: invokestatic  #38                 // Method Animal$class.$init$:(LAnimal;)V
       8: return
}
```

Comment: `Animal.comeToMaster` has no definition. Are you wondering why no abstract method was generated? Maybe it has to do with the lack of an `override` in the subclass?

Comment: Yes why it is not defined there. No override is not required in this case. Neither it affects the generation of bytecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should depend on versions. My outputs are

`$ javap -c Cat.class`

```
Compiled from "Animal.scala"
public class Cat implements Animal {
  public void speak();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #18                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #20                 // String meow....
       5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public void comeToMaster();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #18                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #29                 // String catch me if you can..
       5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public Cat();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #32                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: invokestatic  #36                 // InterfaceMethod Animal.$init$:(LAnimal;)V
       8: return
}
```

`$ javap -c Animal.class`

```
Compiled from "Animal.scala"
public interface Animal {
  public static void speak$(Animal);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #15                 // InterfaceMethod speak:()V
       4: return

  public void speak();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #22                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #24                 // String speaking..
       5: invokevirtual #28                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public abstract void comeToMaster();

  public static void $init$(Animal);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Scala 2.12.4 (jdk 1.8.0_162)

Try to look inside your directory with classes.
Possibly besides abstract class `Animal$class` you have also interface `Animal`.

---

Put `Animal.scala` in one directory and `Animal$class.scala` in a different directory and then call javap there and there. With Scala 2.11.12 outputs are

`$ javap -c Animal.class`

```
Compiled from "Animal.scala"
public interface Animal {
  public abstract void speak();

  public abstract void comeToMaster();
}
```

`$ javap -c Animal$class.class`

```
Compiled from "Animal.scala"
public abstract class Animal$class {
  public static void speak(Animal);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #13                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: ldc           #15                 // String speaking..
       5: invokevirtual #19                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       8: return

  public static void $init$(Animal);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that, Animal.class will have interface and Animal$class.class will have abstract class. I tried to print both but result is same.

Comment: Well, then this is strange behavior of javap and not strange behavior of bytecode. Try to use different decompilers (javap can be more Java-oriented and less Scala-oriented). For example there are plugins for IntelliJ IDEA: Bytecode Viewer, ASM Bytecode Outline.

Comment: Yes it is very strange. I would try.

Comment: It's funny. I checked with Scala 2.11.12 that on contrary to javap Bytecode Viewer and ASM Bytecode Outline shows `Animal` (abstract method `comeToMaster` is there) and not `Animal$class`. Obviously decompilers badly guess which of the classes to show when there are several ones.

Comment: There is workaround. Put `Animal.scala` in one directory and `Animal$class.scala` in a different directory and then call javap there and there. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: But when I see animal$class.class, still there is no comeToMaster method. But it should have both methods.

Comment: Class `Cat` implements interface `Animal`. Abstract method `comeToMaster` is there. Why should it be also in class `Animal$class`? It shouldn't.